# Search according to selected date range

Tags: php, sql, database

Hello wonderful programmers.

I created the following code :

```
if(isset($_GET['from_date']) && isset($_GET['to_date']))
 {
 $from_date = $_GET['from_date'];
 $to_date = $_GET['to_date'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE issuance_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' ";
 $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
 {
     foreach($query_run as $row)
     {
         ?>
```

The thing is, I want to display all members registered during the selected period, but the problem is that it just displays the last two registered entries and neglects the first one. To put it differently, yesterday for example three members have registered, when I select the date to display the members it only displays the last two regestered ones. The same thing happens with any different selected date range.

NB: **$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');** This is how the date is automatically inserted into the database when I insert a new entry.

Here is an example of the registered members:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0rOX.png)

and here is what happens when I select a date:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqp2m.png)

thank you

Comment: Is the `issuance_date` column `DATE` or `DATETIME` or other?

Comment: provide us with some sample data

Comment: The "issuance_date" is DATE.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET['from_date']);` and `var_dump($_GET['to_date']);` show? How are you outputting the HTML in your `foreach($query_run as $row)` loop?

Answer (score 0):

date type cause the problem maybe.

```
BETWEEN 
     CAST('$from_date' AS DATE) AND 
     CAST('$to_date' AS DATE);
```

another thing is the data from user should be checked before using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that but the same problem perists.